# Unable to load Debconf

Tags: debian, perl, upgrade, glibc

I'm trying to upgrade libc on an old machine that runs Linux 2 but I get an error:

```
(Reading database ... 7426 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6 2.2.5-11.8 (using .../libc6_2.24-11+deb9u1_i386.deb) ...
debconf: Unable to load Debconf::Element::Dialog::Error. Failed because: Can't locate Debconf/Element/Dialog/Error.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl/5.6.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.6.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.6.1 /usr/share/perl/5.6.1 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 14) line 2, <GEN1> line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 14) line 2, <GEN1> line 5.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: dpkg-maintscript-helper: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It looks like something with perl but I don't know what to do. Can you inform me what should be done? My goal is to upgrade Perl and to do that I must also upgrade libc iiuc.

Comment: Perl and libc are core parts of the operating system and can not be upgraded without upgrading the entire OS. You can however install a second version of perl that is not used by the system using something like perlbrew. I would consider the above system hosed.

Comment: Are you trying to install a libc .deb from *stretch* on a *woody* system? From the versions it sure looks like you are. If so, that's not sane and I'm surprised you got as far as you did. Even if you somehow accomplished it, the result wouldn't boot—the kernel is far to old for 2.24.

Comment: PS: If you're trying to upgrade, you can't skip Debian releases. So you need to upgrade to Debian 3.1 (Sarge) first. Then keep going, one release at a time, until you get to Stretch. Please review the release notes for each release before upgrading. You honestly should consider just reinstalling, it'll probably be quicker.

Comment: @derobert Thanks a lot for the advice. It's a custom Linux 2.4 that I inherited from ancient project that has been just running with no changes. It is a commercial system I work with that I also try and replicate in a VM to see how and what is possible to upgrade. I found that I could recompile perl to v5.24 and just rename the `usr/bin/perl`, then I could recompile openssl to latest version which was the requirement. But I couldn't yet upgrade clib and I must investigate how much custom code there is and if there is any custom kernel code or just modules. There might be only modules custom.

Comment: @DjDac That... sounds like a nightmare. I'd suggest you go with the firewall option (mentioned in your comment on the answer). Just cataloging all the security vulnerabilities in Woody will take a good amount of time—much less fixing them. And of course, plan to upgrade to something that is supportable.

Comment: @DjDac is there any particular reason you need to upgrade perl?  if not, then do whatever is necessary to minimise the attack surface (i.e. uninstall everything that's not absolutely essential to it doing what it has to do), have firewall rules with default policy REJECT and allow **only** absolutely essential ports/protocols (e.g. most of ICMP, ssh, http, https, DNS replies from the nameserver host listed in /etc/resolv.conf, and whatever else the system needs to do its job).  And if it isn't a VM already, virtualise it.

Comment: @cas Yes, the system owner thinks they need to upgrade openssl because of the debiam guessable cryptography bug in openssl and since there is no .deb for Woody that can get around that exploit, they think that they need to upgrade openssl and regenerate all cryptographic keys.

Comment: did you try just compiling the latest openssl on woody?  or, if that failed, the first version of openssl with that bug fixed (e.g. download the debian sources for it and rebuild the package)?   for something like this, the fewer changes made, the less problems you will encounter.   (and the more changes you need to make, the more that the correct answer becomes "port the server's functionality to the latest stable distro".  i.e. there quickly comes a point where trying to maintain an old distro becomes more work and more likely to break than just upgrading or starting from scratch)

Comment: @cas That's very good to know. I'm still trying to find out how much, if anything, of the kernel 2.4.19 that is custom code and how much can be upgraded. `/etc/issue` says Debian 3.0 and `uname -a` says Linux 2.4.19-custom but the custom code might be modules that are portable even to latest version of Linux. Thank you for the advice. Such an old system has problems upgrading because of libc. Many packages depend on libc and I can't upgrade libc without upgrading Woody(?)

Comment: the `-custom` suffix may just mean the kernel was compiled by the sysadmin at the time (probably using `make-kpkg`), it doesn't necessarily mean that there are any custom changes to the source code.    and, yes, everything in woody was compiled against the same version of libc (and other libraries). upgrading libc may require upgrading or recompiling many other packages, resulting in something that is not "woody" or any other debian release but a custom one-off system based on something that used to be woody.

Comment: @DjDac if you're lucky, there is a kernel source tree in `/usr/src`. And maybe even some pointers somewhere in your kernel showing where it was built from (or even a config file in /boot). Not sure how much of that stuff was around back then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade perl. Ignore debconf for now (later you will tell debconf that you want to receive again the questions).

As first step I would install *bash-static*, just to have a emergency tool in case you cannot regularly boot the system. (Download from Debian site, and install with dpkg -i).

Check what perl module you need (navigate on Debian package site, and check just the essential perl packages). Install them (ev. forcing them with dpkg --force- ). From time to time, try to dpkg --configure --pending, to set up what it is missing.
Finally you should have a working system, and try to update packages regularly.

Comment: +1.   `apt-get -f install` may also be helpful, or even just `apt-get -d -f install` to download the required packages to be installed manually with `dpkg -i`.   Situations like this CAN be resolved, but it takes patience and attention to detail, especially to details like reading apt-get's output to see which key package(s) are blocking the installation/configuration of other packages.   Also, not panicking helps a lot.  Stay calm and methodical, stop and think before every significant action.

Comment: Take a look at the libc versions involved—OP appears to be trying to skip from Debian 3.0 “woody” (released 2002) to Debian 9.0 “stretch” (released 2017).

Comment: @derobert you're right. i hadn't noticed the big jump in libc version numbers.  i withdraw my comment (it's true enough for upgrading to 1 or 2 releases newer, but not jumping from debian 3.0 to 9)

Comment: Please if you can help me find a correct version that I can upgrade to without breaking a good order to upgrade. I still haven't touched the actual system, I'm replicating it in a VM to see what kind of upgrades work. I could recompile perl 5.24 and run that to upgrade openssl to latest version and I'm not sure if the kernel has custom code because it is a custom server with custom hardware for telecommunication and e-commerce. The important matter is to comply with data security standards which we can if we either have firewalls or upgrade to a supported version of the operating system.

Comment: note that if you compile a newer perl and install into /usr/local, that version of perl will not have access to any of the lib*-perl debian packages.  You will have to carefully set up the environment and use `cpan` to compile and install all required modules under, e.g., `/usr/local/share`.   If your woody machine's main purpose is to run a perl app (e.g. website or whatever) then you would be better off creating a new stretch VM and porting the important perl app to the new perl on there.

Comment: @derobert: right, but upgrading glibc should not be a problem. The library is API and ABI compatible. This was the great advantage of "libc6" vs. "libc4" and "libc5": future proof (on the other hand multiple libc libraries can be handled in parallel with SONAME, but also glibc developers know about libraries, so they use also symbol version.  Now I don't remember how many packages were written in C++ (but apt-get were so). These broke because ABI changes (I remember two of such changes).

Comment: @DjDac But I think it is easier, quicker and safer if you install the new version of Debian, and you copy your old data there.  Do not connect to internet which such old debian. It is not just SSL, but also kernel (and network) had several bugs.  If you really need to transfer data but using old software (like many labs), you should use some intermediate machine (better if it will do the real connection, but also building a tunnel is probably enough safe)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for the information. We already have a tunnel to the system and the system is 32-bit. It is not connected to the internet besides the ssh tunnel. Now with a "dummy" Debian 3.0 kernel 2.2 in a VM for testing I could upgrade openssl to version 0.9.8g which is supposed to not have the vulnerability. I think that means that I can upgrade openssl with the production system. The latest version of openssl didn't support the architecture (the machine is an IBM xSeries 845). The system owners have not changed the system in many years and just left it running.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The system is also running custom hardware as well as custom changes to Linux so it is a meticulous task to even understand what is doable. There is almost no documentation and a lot of custom C code that is running. I am looking manually at processes to see what the system is doing.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi RE: API/ABI compatibility.  Theoretically, yes, maybe, somewhat true.  Practically, though, there have been several releases of libc in the **15 years** separating "woody" and "stretch" that have introduced incompatibilities with previous versions, and there are also dependencies and other entanglements between libc and particular versions of other libraries and the kernel that greatly complicate the issue.  The chance of even compiling the latest libc6 on woody is zero or so low it's indistinguishable from zero.  The chance of installing a stretch libc6 pkg is even lower.

Comment: @cas: I disagree. glibc is made to be compiled on other OSes and old machines, so it can be compiled (not with all modern Linux support, and probably just with old syscall convention).  Really: it is not theoretical, it is just the way of glibc (and Linux) is done: never break past, just expand APIs. For this reason the 2038 bug is problematic. This really requires some ABI/API change. IIRC woody boot tools were (simple) C, boot and perl, so less problems. Both libraries can also left in parallel. But this is a nice experiment, and I just found old Debian CDROOM (from woody time).

Comment: In theory, theory and practice are the same.  In practice, they're not.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The libc6/glibc news file is very clear that libc6 2.24 requires (on x86) Linux 2.6.32 or later (and Debian's news file says 3.2). It will not work with 2.4. Even going back to glibc 2.16, that requires Linux 2.6. According to Debian's news file, you need a glibc before 2.5 to work with 2.4 kernels.